# ClassNotFound Exception While running java program from apache Spark

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I have Compiled Java program and attempted to run using spark but it is showing  ClassNotFound Exception even if class file exists there.[image]

```
    package org.apache.spark.examples;

    import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
    import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
    import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
    import org.apache.spark.api.java.function;  

    public final class JavaHelloWorld
    {
         public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
         {

         SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaSparkPi");
         JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
         System.out.println("Hello World... Niyat From Apache Spark");
         }
    }
```

Comment: It would be better if you post your code and stack trace in text instead of image.

Answer (score 2):

You have to write the exact name of the class, you have the initial `j` lowercase:

`JavaHelloWorld`

Comment: Is the class inside the spark-examples-1.1.10-hadoop1.0.4.jar? Because it is not being found.

Comment: Yes. It is inside the spark-examples-1.1.10